# Can NSClassFromString use in App Store?

Tags: objective-c

Seems the `NSClassFromString` can create object on the fly based on the String, so, if I use the `performSelector` and pass another string, I can call almost all the method on the fly...Is this violate the App Store guideline and being rejected? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It only violates the guidelines if you use it to access private Apple API. If you're using it for your API, public API, optional API content then it's fine.

Answer (score 1):

The mechanism is totally legitimate. Just don't use it for private api calls.

Answer (score 0):

For creating your own objects yes you can. It is [officially](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/miscellaneous/foundation_functions/reference/reference.html) documented so, as long as you do not use it to call private apis, you are free to use it.

Comment: But if I parse the string on the fly, which calling the private apis, Apple still can't control that, right??

Comment: If you make any direct or indirect call to private apis they will find it. Even in a future update, they will.